# How to fix error: 'Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera' does not contain a definition for 'IsFocusAtPointSupported' ... in windows phone 7.1 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, camera, setfocus, autofocus

I'm doing application about camera focus in Windows Phone 7.1

I referenced http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.devices.photocamera(v=vs.92).aspx and added assembly:  Microsoft.Phone to my project reference but I get this error : 'Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera' does not contain a definition for 'IsFocusAtPointSupported' and no extension method 'IsFocusAtPointSupported' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

I intalled:
Microsoft Visual C# 2010,
Microsoft Windows Phone Developer Tools 7.1 (Beta) - ENU,
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate - ENU Service Pack 1.

Thanks for any idea.

Comment: Install the release version http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=27570

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://www.findthatfile.com/search-11161323-hZIP/winrar-winzip-download-justin-windowsphone-buildfromlocalfiles-zip.htm download the zip file and extract it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone and extract your required dll there.

Go to your project RightClick References and then add reference to Microsoft.Devices.dll